# Problema al descargar archivos

Tags: redes, descarga

Estoy tratando de navegar al mismo tiempo que descargo cualquier programa o juego, ya sea vía Steam o Origin me ha pasado igual, mientras descargo el archivo se pierde toda conexión a internet, menos en la descarga y por lo tanto no puedo usar el navegador para buscar lo que necesite mientras tanto. He estado buscando información al respecto pero solo encuentro el típico error de si descargo un archivo se va el internet por completo, cosa que no es mi caso ya que descarga el archivo correctamente a buena velocidad pero no me deja hacer nada más. También he estado buscando y he encontrado una posible solución que es quitar el limite de ancho de banda de Windows 10 pero tengo mis dudas al respecto ya que siempre he podido descargar y ver el navegador al mismo tiempo.

Comment: Tu PC puede estar infectada te recomiendo realizar un análisis en busca de infecciones, en administrador de tareas en rendimiento ves el uso de la tarjeta de red me imagino que debe estar alto.

Comment: Lo acababa de formatear, estaba instalando los programas que necesito.